# Interactive SSH works on Mac host, but SCP and non-interactive commands over SSH fail?

Tags: macos, ssh, scp

I've got two Macs, both with sshd enabled via System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login: On. I can successfully log into both of them and run commands in an interactive shell using

```
$ ssh <hostname>.local
```

I'm using simple password authentication (no SSH keys), and have confirmed with `sudo sshd -t` that there are no issues with `sshd_config`.

However, if I try to only execute a command on the remote machine,

```
$ ssh <hostname>.local echo foo
```

the command fails (*i.e.,* exit status 1 / nothing on `STDOUT`). Specifically, verbose (debugging) output seems to look *nearly* identical to what I get when successfully executing such a command on my Linux VPS — the only difference being the exit status:

#### Mac Host

```
$ ssh -v <hostname>.local echo foo 2>&1 | tail -n10
Password:
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: echo foo
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2300, received 2552 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 86838.6, received 96353.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

#### Linux VPS Host

```
$ ssh -v <vps> echo foo 2>&1 | tail
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: echo foo
foo
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3304, received 2744 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 11505.5, received 9555.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Furthermore, `scp` fails with `lost connection`.

What's going on here?

Comment: I suspect you'll need some packet captures to figure this one out.

Comment: Do you get any more useful details when you run `ssh -vvv` for maximum verbosity? How about verbose logs out of `sshd` on the server?

Comment: Good questions! I don't have the client machine with me, and I had to add a `LogLevel` line to the host machine's `sshd_config`, so I'll report back later on tonight.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that something in your .bashrc or similar file on the server is causing your shell to exit prematurely for non-interactive sessions. Did you modify your .bashrc or similar files on the server recently?

Comment: @Kenster was absolutely right. I had the following line at the top of my `.bashrc`: `[[ $- =~ i ]] || exit 1` (where `exit 1` should instead be `return`). Unfortunately, I tested this on my VPS, and in the course of experimenting with it, removed the conditional at the front. So now, it looks like I might have to nuke my VPS :(